# Python polymorphic objects calling base class methods instead of subclass method

Tags: python, django, polymorphism

I have the following models in Django. I have reasons not to make `Animal` an abstract base class.

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    sound = "none"
    def ClassType(self):
        return 'animal'

class Cat(Animal):
    animal_id = models.OneToOneField(Animal,parent_link=True)
    sound = "meow"
    def ClassType(self):
        return 'cat'

class Dog(Animal):
    animal_id = models.OneToOneField(Animal,parent_link=True)
    sound = "bow"
    def ClassType(self):
        return 'dog'
```

I query for a set of Animals as

`query = Animal.objects.all()`

Result is a list of necessarily only Dogs and Cats. However, on calling

`query[0].ClassType`

I only get `animal`. All the objects in "query" give me `animal` while I want to get `dog` or `cat` depending on the instance. What am I not understanding in the Python polymorphic world and how do I fix it?

Comment: do `query[0].dog.ClassType` or `query[0].cat.ClassType`

Comment: Thanks - that is an option I was unaware of. However, does this mean I need to know the subclass a priori or at least iterate through all possible subclasses to see which ones exist? Is there a better way ?

Comment: Why do you need a one to one relationship with animal when your classes are already inheriting from it?

Comment: The OneToOneField exists because I need to populate the database through an initial_fixtures.yaml file and Django needs explicit instantiation of the superclass and subclass objects which I can relate through that field.

Comment: Django polymorphism is broken. You just learned how.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dog and cat object using a dot notation (like an attribute). The query `Animal.objects.all()` is going to return all animals which will include all cats and dogs.

```
qs = Animal.objects.all()
for animal in qs:
    try:
        obj = animal.cat
        # its a cat
    except AttrbuteError:
        # its a dog
        obj = animal.dog
```

As you see there is just a glitch in identifying which one is a dog and which one is a cat, a good approach will be to set a temporary attribute in your animal model:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    sound = "none"

    def is_cat(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_is_cat'):
            self._is_cat = Cat.objects.filter(animal_id=self).exists()
        return self._is_cat
```

Now you can just simply do:

```
qs = Animal.objects.all()
for animal in qs:
    if animal.is_cat():
        # this is a cat
    else:
        # dog
```

Comment: And then you run into the strange situation where a Django object can be both a `Cat` *and* a `Dog`, yet there's no way to represent that in Python.

Comment: I know this is knit picky, but: is_cat() should not be defined on the Animal class. Instead, you should use: "if isinstance(animal, Cat):" rather than "if animal.is_cat():". The reason is, is_cat() will be inherited by all other non-Cat classes which inherit Animal, not just cats. This means one more method which in most cases, probably won't be used.

Comment: @Joshua: Except Django polymorphism is so broken that `isinstance()` will always return `False` if you query from `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `ClassType` a method, you should make it an actual field, and store the type of the object when you save. Otherwise, as you discover, when you query for Animals, you only get Animals, rather than the subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I fall in the same problem, so here is my solution for it:

I used the [django_polymorphic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_polymorphic) app, it is very useful for several reasons, but it provides attributes for the corresponding model instance and the name of it, that you can use to fix your problem.

So you could change your base class to look like the following:

```
class Animal(PolymorphicModel):
    sound = "none"

    def ClassType(self):
        polymorphic_attr_name = self.name.lower().replace(" ", "")  # Get the name of the attribute that points to the instance
        if polymorphic_attr_name == 'animal':
            return 'animal'
        instance = getattr(self, polymorphic_attr_name)
        return instance.ClassType()
```

Then you can forgot about any animal subclasses. It works for me, hope this helps.

Comment: I think you forgot to ```return instance.ClassType()```